# Which tool can help me design a 3x3 Matrix in 3D?

Tags: windows, open-source

I would like to know which windows OS tool can I use to design a 3D 3x3 Matrix representation. A software that I can draw something like this with. But would allow me to input Text in the boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer IMHO depends on the quality you need for the output and whether you want to be able to change the cube or not.

It you need to change the cube as well, then probably you would use [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), model the cube as a 3D model, use a texture to add the text, set up some lights to make it look nice etc. Blender [is open source](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) and you'll find an installer [for Windows](https://www.blender.org/download/). Be aware that it will take a while to learn Blender.

If you don't need to change the cube and just want to add text, I would recommend [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/). It's [open-source as well](https://inkscape.org/en/about/license/) and has [an installer for Windows](https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.92.3/).

The workflow is quite straight forward there:

1. Add some text
2. Scale the text to fit inside one of the "rectangle"s
3. Click on the text with the arrow tool until it shows an up-down arrow on the right side of the text
4. Click that arrow and drag it upwards until the text lines up with the perspective line

The screenshot shows 3 finished texts and one in progress. You can certainly do better than I with a little bit more time.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [freemium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) online software, for the sake of simplicity (you do not need to install anything).

However, I highly encourage you to use open source software if you have time to learn them and plan to use them on the long run (then I would recommend [OpenJSCAD](https://openjscad.org/) or [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) for 3D modeling, and [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) or [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) ; although there are probably simple open source drawing online apps).

#### 3D

The [Sketchup online app](https://app.sketchup.com/app#) is definitely the most accessible 3D modeling software for simple use cases.

You will be able to drag a rectangle on the "ground" with the *rectangle tool* (currently the 6th button on the left toolbar). If you need to give precise dimensions to your rectangle, just type dimensions like `50,50` on your keyboard just after dragging the rectangle with the mouse.

Then you can extrude your rectangle with the *extrude tool*, just next to the rectangle tool. You can force extrude multiple times in the same direction with the alt key pressed while dragging.

#### Text

To add text on your resulting image, I highly recommend [Figma](https://www.figma.com/). It is so simple to use that I believe I do not need to explain how it works.

#### Other recomendations

If you know how to code, and need your matrix to be editable, I would recommend using [three.js](https://threejs.org/) to create a small javascript webpage.

[Slant](https://www.slant.co/topics/1559/~best-3d-modeling-software) and [AlternativeTo.net](https://alternativeto.net/) are good websites to compare software or find recommendations.

***Note***

I am a developer and digital artist with 10 years of experience, I used many different 2D and 3D modeling tools.